# Can't access various secure websites (https) through Firefox 71/Google Chrome/Microsoft Edge

Tags: firefox, https

I haven't been able to access popular websites on Firefox like

- Geeks for Geeks or
- Notepad++ and
- not even the official website for Avast Antivirus.

The 'lock' icon showed on other webpages doesn't show up on these pages and instead the 'i' symbol saying the connection isn't secure shows up, even when I manually type https in the navigation bar. The exact message:

### [image: FireFox Error]

**I tried using Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome too, but the issue still remains.**

There aren't any firewall changes I've done manually but even so, what are the methods I can use to rectify these problems?

Answer (score 1):

#### An error occurred during a connection to ... PR_CONNECT_ABORTED_ERROR

I can reproduce this error when trying to connect to websites that are blocked by the ISP I'm currently connected to (for example torrent search sites are blocked by some ISPs).

Notes:

- I have Avast installed, but it is not set to scan network traffic.
- I have verified that it is an ISP issue by trying two different IPS, one which has publicly stated they are blocking torrent search sites, on a different ISP the same request succeeds.
- It can also be caused by an incorrect system date and time (make sure your computer is set to the correct date, time and time zone).

If you are sure that your date, time and time zone are set correctly, and your ISP is not blocking these websites, then a check for viruses/malware etc may be your next step.

Comment: [If not even a single byte has been received from the remote site, and a read
error is detected, an automatic retry should happen.
  This is currently done when PR_CONNECT_ABORTED_ERROR or PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR
is seen (and communicated using NS_ERROR_NET_RESET).](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106865).  In other words, the ISP (or Avast I suppose) is indeed blocking the connection.

Comment: @Ramhound LOL. Valid point, but that is a link to an 18 year old closed bug ;)

Comment: It might be 18 years old;  But it tells me `PR_CONNECT_ABORTED_ERROR` is an error that is displayed when 0 bytes is transferred.